# parsing facebook html with python 2.7

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using python 2.7 and I am trying to extract the personal ids of the people who liked my facebook page photos. My code is:

```
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize 
br = mechanize.Browser() 
htmltext = br.open("url").read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext) 
search = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'_5j0e fsl fwb fcb'}) 
print search
```

But when run this code I get empty brackets [ ]. Also, when I run the same code but "print soup" instead of the "print search", I get the HTML but the ids are not there, I even Ctrl+F to look for them but they are not there, so it seems that my code didn't extract these parts at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, you MUST use the Graph API to get data. It is a pretty simple API call: `/post-id/likes`

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes